# WooCommerce hide unexisting variations

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have 2 products with different properties. 
1 product has 5 variations configured and the other 120. 
However, the maximum possible variations for both products are 144 (not all variations are configured).

We notice that the product with 5 variations only shows the 5 variations (so other variations cannot be chosen in the listbox). 
But for the product with 120 variations it shows the 144 variations.
This sometimes leads to the message "Sorry, this product is not available. Pick another combination".

Is it possible for product 2 to only have the 120 configured varations show up in the listbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found it ourselves, this is the solution. 
Add the following snippet in functions.php

```
function wc_increase_variation_threshold( $product ) {
    return 500;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold', 'wc_increase_variation_threshold', 10, 2 );
```